# Running a bash script with mandatory arguments

Tags: bash, getopt, optparse

I want my bash script to be working only when I type

```
bash.sh --subj directoryname --input filename --all
```

`--subj`, `--input`, and `--all` are all required to make the script work, and the `--all` argument does not require any input.

If either `--subj` or `--input` is missing, I want the following message to be printed:

Please provide both directory name and file name.

If `--all` argument is missing, I want to print:

```
Please use --all option.
```

I fix a script from Github using `optparse`.

```
source optparse.bash
optparse.define short=s long=subj desc="subject name" variable=subj
optparse.define short=i long=input desc="The file to process" variable=input
optparse.define short=a long=all desc="all option" variable=all value=true default=false

source $(optparse.build)
if [ "$subj" == "" ]; then
   echo "ERROR: Please provide a directory name"
   exit 1
fi

if [ "$input" == "" ]; then
   echo "ERROR: Please provide an input"
   exit 1
fi

if [ "$all" == "" ]; then
   echo "ERROR: Please use the all option"
   exit 1
fi
```

https://github.com/nk412/optparse/blob/master/sample_head.sh

Using this code, it does say please provide a directory name when I missed --subj or -input. but when I miss all, it does not say any error. do you know why is that?

Comment: Why have the options at all? Just use `bash.sh directoryname filename`.

Comment: @chepner: I need to make this work as it is for a certain reason.. so I have to use --subj, --input, and --all :(

Comment: You should only need to do `source $(optparse.build)` once.

Comment: You need a space before `]`.  You might want to try http://shellcheck.net/ to catch simple errors before asking here for human review.

Comment: Options which are not optional are a oxymoron.

Comment: @tripleee: I used source once in my actual script. It was just my mistake when I write it in here. sorry. and thx for suggesting shellcheck.net. I didn't knew this site.

Answer (score 0):

From their doc:

> Flags are defined in exactly the same way, but with an extra parameter value that is assigned to the variable.

```
optparse.define short=v long=verbose desc="Set flag for verbose mode" variable=verbose_mode value=true default=false
```

This is exactly what you want, flags are options that don't require arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> optparse.define short=… value=true default=false
> ```
>
> I edited my question using your suggestion. but I couldn't fix the
>   problem..

In your case, you don't want the `default=false` clause, so it's:

```
optparse.define short=a long=all desc="all option" variable=all value=true
```

That's because the test `"$all" == ""` doesn't take effect if `$all` is `false`.